# DML Exception on send Email quick action

Tags: lightning-experience, send-email, lightning-quickaction

I am trying to send an email using existing default send Email quick action and once I hit the send button it prompts following error.

"**Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, RecordID__c not specified: []**"

I am pretty new to salesforce and could someone help me sort this out?

Comment: Can you share the code behind the upsert functionality?

Comment: Enable Debug Logs, try to debug the error.